# How to merge two data frames to show unique count of rows?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I have 2 Dataframes in my project as shown below.

```
Table 1 
Order_id  Prod_id   Price
A           AA       5
B           BB       10
C           CC       15 
D           AA       5
E           CC       20

Table 2
Prod_id   Price
 AA       5
 BB       10
 CC       15 
 CC       20
```

My target table is as below:

```
Table 3:
Prod_id   Price   Order_Count  
AA         5          2
BB         10         1
CC         15         1
CC         20         1
```

This is what I've tried so far.

```
merged_table = pd.merge(order_items[['product_id','price']].explode('price'),order_items[['product_id','price','order_id']], on=['product_id','price'])
merged_table = merged_table.drop_duplicates()
merged_table
order_counts = merged_table.groupby(['product_id', 'price']).size().reset_index()
order_counts.rename(columns={0:'order_count'},inplace=True)
order_counts.sort_values(by='order_count',ascending=False)
order_counts['No_of_orders'].sum()
```

My code is working but the order count is not matching up with the expected count from the dataset. The target table should be able to scan the Prod_id as well as the price of the specific product. If the Prod_id and the price is the same, then it should eliminate the row. But if the prod_id is the same but the price for the same product is different, then it should consider it to be a unique row.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to just count the orders from the first dataframe and merge this count with the second:

```
orders_by_prod = table1.groupby("Prod_id")["Order_id"].nunique().rename("Order_count").reset_index()
table3 = pd.merge(table2, orders_by_prod, on="Prod_id", how="left")
table3["Order_count"] = table3["Order_count"].fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to first calculate the counts of table1 and then merge with table 2:

```
table1_gp = table1.groupby(['Prod_id', 'Price'], as_index=False)['Order_id'].count()
table2.merge(table1_gp, on=['Prod_id', 'Price']).rename(columns={'Order_id': 'Order_Count'})
```

Output:

```
  Prod_id  Price  Order_Count
0      AA      5            2
1      BB     10            1
2      CC     15            1
3      CC     20            1
```